# Why is the infinite preservation of information an essential assumption to be made when developing physics laws?

Tags: information

First of all, my current knowledge consists of Physics 101 in public high school.

Regarding the idea of information not being destroyed, this makes complete sense to me.

The thing that doesn't quite make sense to me is why:

> It's fundamental for all our laws of physics that information can never be lost.

As stated at 4:32 of [this Kurzgesagt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWO-cvGETRQ).

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

*Here is an answer with two layers.*

**1)** The root reasons are almost the same as the ones that led us to energy conservation (and other conservation laws that are not *proved* to be true, but instead elevated *by us* to be physical *laws* since they constitute the most succeeding set of principles in physics -- even "more serious" ways of expressing the conservation laws in physics (e.g. Noether's theorem) rely on the naïve observation that the laws of physics have symmetry). We ask our physical models to capture the reversibility that we find in our physical laws and this, in turn, comes back as an assertion that is named as conservation of information. After all, it is *sensible* for us to welcome such an assertion.

**2)**
It's *embedded* in our mathematical contexture of QM where the time evolution exposes reversibility. The physical transformations that lead from one state to another render information itself recoverable. Imagine any physical action (a known example is burning a book), *in the theoretical sense* run the time backwards for that action -- the physical procedure that hosts the action will be there, since the computation that carried out this physical action allows it to be so.

*But then*, if you go on and ask, "Why *it is* embedded in our mathematical contexture in the first place?", I will say that finding the essential base as you requested is somewhat a philosophical issue which should be touched upon here only by stating that associating **1)**, which reflects our demands, and **2)**, which reflects our mathematics, finally brings us to a stage in which we will find ourself start asking "Why?" indefinitely (Maybe it's a nice point to share [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA) by Feynman). Therefore, I hope you are satisfied at least with layer **1)** or layer **2)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one answer I got from an expert, I will simplify by omitting the mathematical derivations.

Asserting that information is a conserved quantity means that information does not just pop into our world by magic, all by itself and out of nowhere. If we then assert that information tells us a story about things that have happened, conserving information then means that stuff does not happen all on its own- at least in the sense that macroscopic effects in our world do not pop into and out of existence or jump from place to place without causes that precede them.

From this we can go on to state that for everything that *can* happen, the sum of all the attendant probabilities must be 1. If it's greater than 1, I interpret that as analogous to the case in which a cause had two unrelated effects (you fired one bullet at a target and two adjacent targets got holes in them, as if you had fired twice); if it's less than 1 I interpret that as analogous to the case that a cause had no effect (you fired a bullet at a target and no hole at all appears, just as if you had not fired your gun).

The conclusion is that conservation of information means that causes precede effects and specific causes produce specific effects. These are essential attributes of any model (i.e., set of laws) of the world we could choose to write down.

If you write down a set of laws which allow things to happen without cause or prevent things from happening with cause, then you are describing a world ruled by magic, not physics.

As usual, I invite the experts here to weigh in with their own responses.

Comment: im not sure information is conserved, I would think that like entropy, it does increase.

Comment: We have the reasoning that is based on our **mathematical fabric**, that's why we can talk about "entropy increase" in relevant cases. What would be the mathematical fabric that would motivate your reasoning on "information increase", one might ask.

Comment: @GulceKardes Im not sure i understand your question. But I'd  say entropy and quantity of information are the same and increase for the same reasons. In lower entropy states, information is structured and therefore can be *compressed*. When information can be compressed I would say the quantity of information decreases

Answer (score -1):

Because quantity of information is closely related to entropy. If information were to decrease, then so could entropy and that would break the 2nd law of thermodynamics:

> The second law of thermodynamics states that the total entropy of an
>   isolated system can never decrease over time.

And [according to wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) this principle is tied to many other things. The most fundamental one in my opinion is the "arrow of time", but I believe it deserves a lot of discussion.

Comment: If information were replaced by random bits, entropy would not decrease and information would be lost.

Comment: information would be *changed* not lost. The purpose of physics is largely about making sense of bits that seem random. In your case physics would immediately ask "what process did scramble the bits to a seemingly random state?"

Comment: If it's a *seemingly random state*, information is not lost. If it's an *actually random state*, entropy may increase and information is lost. And this thought experiment shows how information can be lost, and not break the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: A thought experiment demands invoquing things that are conceivably possible (though not feasible at the moment).
But you are invoquing an impossible construct: a randomizer that is both in the system in order to change things and out the system so that changing things leaves no trace.

I could similarly say that angels push around the planets so that they orbit the sun, therefore gravity doesnt exist. With angels *anything is possible*.

Comment: In other words, if you fixed your thought experiment, so that the randomizer is fully in the system, then the information wouldnt be lost and it wouldnt decrease either after shuffling it around. I could even grant you that the initial bits are truely randomized if you only look at them, but but some extra bits were created somewhere else by the randomizer that could reverse the randomization. Like we create passwords to decypher encrypted data.

Comment: What is conceivably impossible about a randomizer that is in the system?  On whose authority do you say that God does not play dice with the universe?

Comment: if the randomizer is in the system, it cannot *change* bits (=spend energy) without leaving a trace (=extra bits/password) that could decypher the randomized bits.
Playing dice is one thing, changing the numbers on the dice free of charge is another.

Comment: These are completely unwarranted assumptions. Why do you think the randomizer is an active entity, and not just parts of the laws of nature?

Comment: this is warranted, any change of information requires an expenditure of energy, heck, that's how energy is defined. I already explained why your randomizer couldnt loose information *if* it was to obey laws of nature.